# Jest & Supertest await no respond

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have written a following test case:

```
test("should respond with a 200 tatus code",async () => {
    const response = await request(users).post("/signup").send({"email":"wwww12dSD3","password":"adasdasdas","username":"adasdasdasdaYrrrrY"})
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200)
})
```

Corresponding node js route is

```
router.route('/signup').post(jsonParser,async (req, res) => {
    //create new User
    //Turn email to lowercase since email is case insensitive
    console.log(req.body);
    const email = req.body.email.toLowerCase();
    const password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    const username = req.body.username;
    
    //check if user already exists
    const oldUser = User.find({email: email});
    if ((await oldUser).length >= 1){
        res.status(400).json('User already exists');
    } else {
        //save new user
        const newUser = new User({email, password, username});
        console.log(newUser);
        newUser.save()
            .then(() => res.status(200).json('Sign up successful'))
            .catch(err => res.status(500).json('Error: ' + err));
    }
});
```

I got an error

```
    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```

However It can get the reqbody but it can not get the

```
console.log(newUser);
```

so no respone was sent out

but i can get the correct respond when using insomnia

Any suggestion regarding this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you should use done() function in jest at the last of the async test function. otherwise it will wait forever

Comment: how can i use the end() function

Comment: sorry not end() it should be done() as like this
https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous